# How to pass Button's id in onPress - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to pass a button's id as an argument for a function triggered by the onPress event.

```
setCategory = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id)
}
render(){
    return(
        <Button title="News" id={15} onPress={this.setCategory}/>
    )
}
```

so `15` should be logged in the terminal but i'm getting `undefined`. This is what i would do in Reactjs but i'm new to React Native so i don't know if the syntax is wrong.

Comment: is this button your custom component.

Comment: it's a react-native component

Comment: i'm taking the id from the prop i just put the 15 in there for the sake of the demonstration

Comment: If you show how you get the property which is put into `id` I can edit my answer for you.

Comment: so i'm actually rendering the Button in a FlatList component, so it should be something like this `<Button title={item.name} id={item.id} onPress={this.setCategory}/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If id comes from a prop, then you can do this.

```
<Button title="News" id={this.props.prop_where_id_is} onPress={() => this.setCategory(this.props.prop_where_id_is)} />
```

Then your `setCategory` becomes

```
setCategory = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: thanks man, it worked!
but why is it like this? It's not like react js

Answer (score 1):

You can get the props with the help of 'ref'

```
            <Button
                id='5'
                title='sss'
                ref={ref => this.button = ref}
                onPress={() => console.log(this.button.props.id)}
            />
```

in your case

```
             onPress = (id) => {
               console.log(id);
              }
                ...
                 <Button
                    id='5'
                    title='sss'
                    ref={ref => this.button = ref}
                    onPress={() => 
                      this.onPress(this.button.props.id)
                    }
                    />
```

Comment: thanks man, i tried but the other guy's way is a bit cleaner and more straight foward